Disconnect/Network issues with Windows 11 Pro 24H2 and python yfinance() library
Posted on Github yfinance() but no response yet... My computer's been having issues with Windows 11 Pro 24H2 (latest builds since around October) and python yfinance() library. Quotes run for a while then stop. If I reboot computer they start again but stop after a while again. This happens before Regular Trading Hours (RTH <9:30am), or during pre-market when quotes/data is sparser (less active). Once RTH starts there is no disconnect. Python is allowed through firewall. I had upgraded to 0.2.50 but had to downgrade to 0.2.18 which seems to be a little more stable. I also have Linux Mint installed (dual boot) and there are no problems on that OS. I've also tried Mint through VirtualBox and no problems there. Just Windows 11 Pro 24H2 (recent builds). I tried to downgrade Windows but it won't let me, always updates to latest. I reset the network and firwall but still an issue. It must be a network/security/firewall issue or something, not sure. Seems like Windows might close connection if not active after a certain period of time if low/no activity. I don't know anything about networking and firewall. If anyboday has any suggestions it would be appreciated. tia

I added the following to registry:
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters
TcpTimedWaitDelay: Set it to 30000 (30 seconds)
KeepAliveTime: set it to 60000 (1 minute)
KeepAliveInterval: Set it to 1000 (1 second)
I also downloaded and ran TCPOptimizer and ran that:
https://www.speedguide.net/downloads.php
Screenshots on this forum for TCP settings:
https://www.speedguide.net/forums/viewtopic.php?p=2444120&sid=16b70986864e26024f00c490c330a73e#p2444120
Seems to be working so far. I will update if anything changes.
